# Why is this javascript sound loop so inconsistent?

Tags: javascript, loops, audio

This sound loop is slightly inconsistent (it should play three beeps once per second) when the page it's on is in focus.  However, when on another tab, or another window, the beep is much slower (actually it seems like it's almost exactly 5x slower) and even more inconsistent.  I've tried on the latest chrome and firefox, and get similar results.  IE refuses to play anything at all, but that's fine.

```
var snd = new Audio("data:audio/wav;base64,omitted, see jsfiddle");
var beepcount = 0;
var beep = function() {
    if ((beepcount++ % 5) < 3) {
        snd.play();
    }
    setTimeout(beep,200);
}
beep();
```

Why is it so inconsistent?  Is this a result of setTimeout()?  Is there an alternative better suited for what I'm trying to do?  (What I'm trying to do is play loud annoying beeps until the user closes the page.  Yes, I have good reasons.  :) )

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eb0fckrm/ (WARNING: loud beeps)

Comment: For clarity, the timing doesn't need to be precise, it's just a basic alarm sound.  But I figure that it should at least be fairly regular, even if it's not precise, but it seems very inconsistent.

Comment: You need to correct for the variability of the delay. The actually delay is allowed to be longer than the delay specified but never shorter.  Measure the difference and adjust your delay to compensate.

Comment: Dan, it seems like the "variability" is as much as 400% of the intended delay, which can't be compensated for (It would result in missed beeps, which would just be a complicated way to replicate the original problem)

Comment: Have you tried using `setInterval`?

Comment: Just did.  https://jsfiddle.net/eb0fckrm/1/  Same problem.  They're basically the same function in practice anyway.

Comment: This may be a wild guess, but it could be normal browser behaviour. If you activate a new tab, then memory may be throttled for previously opened tabs. Not really sure what I'm going on about, so take with a pinch of salt.

Comment: [MDN `setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval): _“Starting in Gecko 5.0 (Firefox 5.0 / Thunderbird 5.0 / SeaMonkey 2.2), intervals are clamped to fire no more often than once per second in inactive tabs.”_

Comment: Thank you, @Xufox.  Using [riffwave](http://www.codebase.es/riffwave/) I was able to generate a one-second audio file to play on loop instead of the base64 file played on timeouts, and it works fine now.  :)